# Why does Holder use the term 'habibi'?

Tags: the-killing

In the American version of *The Killing*, detective Stephen Holder is seen using the term *habibi* several times when talking to his sister and his nephew, *Habibi* is an Arabic term of endearment widely used with close family members and friends. From what I can tell, Holder doesn't seem to have any Arab roots, so why the seemingly random use of that term?

Comment: I'm assuming you're talking about the 2nd season, correct?

Comment: @DustinDavis - I don't remember which season it was to be honest. I think I first heard it when Holder was leaving a voice message for his nephew.

Comment: [This might shed some light](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20060817083108AAYwBfK), but doesn't explain why he'd be using the masculine form of the word for the sister (*habibti* according to the post).

Comment: @Paulster2 - Oh I'm well aware of the meaning of the word (after all, I speak Arabic). What's bothering me is why Holder would use that word.

Comment: I figured as much, but was just adding comment for others understanding and to muddy the waters even more, it would seem.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's because Holder is supposed to embody the addict/cool/street guy. He is the guy that knows how to get secrets out of people and how to get things done discretely. Basically he is a smooth talker! So it makes sense that he would know a few words of a different language.

Also I don't see why he can't also have a knowledge of various languages! It's upsetting that would bother someone. I'm pretty sure there were a few episodes that featured Arabic speaking in regards to the mosque and the high school teacher.

Comment: Not convincing enough.

Comment: Here's the thing. Those were the *only* Arabic words he used throughout the series. Sure they could be just random words he picked up, but why those.

Comment: What?! It totally makes sense! We know that Habibi is a term of endearment. But did you also know it's a slang term as well. In regard to Holder's street style this makes sense. I think it also adds to his character. The writers don't explain those words, but want us, as an audience, to know Holder had a history with the family because of it. They have their our affectionate names, in another language at that. It adds to the mystery of holder as a character.

Answer (score 1):

Let's all not forget that Holder was an avid book reader, and general seeker of knowledge. He is interested in many cultures, and draws from many religions...

**ALL WHILE HE IS TEACHING HIMSELF**

So he might not be getting the exact details right, although he is getting the general messages from the teachings, and applying them to his own life.

I personally do not know any Arabic, so I can't weigh in on if the term was used correctly or not within the context.

I just thought it was important to point out that even if he is a white male with no ties to any ethnic cultures/ religions, it does not mean that he isn't knowledgeable about them.